# Reduce price for first billing cycle (Stripe)

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to reduce first billing cycle price when creating a stripe recurring price?. I read the Stripe Node.js documentation but didn't find any clue to reduce the first billing cycle price. Now I am thinking to attach a coupon when the price is applied to a subscription. Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking to charge less for the first billing cycle, the [coupon route](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-coupon) as you mentioned above makes the most sense. When [creating the coupon](https://stripe.com/docs/api/coupons/create#create_coupon-duration), you’d want to add `duration:once` so it’s only applicable for one time usage.